# How does ruby support multiple inheritance?

Tags: ruby

How does ruby support **multiple inheritance** so that I can inherit from multiple classes?

Comment: is google broken? not my downvote BTW

Comment: checkout [Mixins in Ruby](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_modules.htm)

Comment: @MitchWheat I need authoritative answers, if I have to look into Google I wouldn't need a site like stackoverflow.com. Please abstain if you don't feel like answering.

Comment: Disappointed that this question got closed.  I don't see anything in the FAQ that says "don't ask simple questions with straightforward answers."  Seems like a perfect use of SO to me.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this question whatsoever.  Multiple inheritance is a clearly defined concept against which to compare Ruby's features.  Mods what are you thinking?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ruby does not directly have multiple inheritance. Ruby has something similar though: [mixins](http://docs.ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html#S2). For example:

```
module M; end
module N; end

class C
  include M
  include N
end

C.ancestors  #=>  [C, N, M, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Note that mixins are *not* multiple inheritance, but instead mostly eliminate the need for it.

Comment: is Ruby's way of single inheritance with mixin similar to Java's single inheritance with "implementing an Interface"?

Comment: @太極者無極而生 Sort of. A Java class can implement several interfaces the way a Ruby class can include many modules. But a Java interface has no implementation, only abstract methods, whereas Ruby has no concept of abstract methods and modules include an implementation.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall With Java 8 you can have (default) implementation in interfaces.